# Should I worry about releasing resources in this case?

Tags: c#, dispose

Let's say I have a class Collection which holds a list of Items.

```
public class Collection
{
    private List<Item> MyList;
    //...
}
```

I have several instances of this Collection class which all have different MyLists but share some Items.
For example: There are 10 Items, Collection1 references Items 1-4, Collection2 has Items 2-8 and Collection3 4,7,8 and 10 on its List.

I implemented this as follows: I have one global List which holds any Items available. Before I create a new Collection I check if there are already Items I need in this list -- if not I create the Item and add it to the global List (and to the Collection of course).

The problem I see is that those Items will never be released - even if all Collections are gone, the memory they consume is still not freed because the global list still references them.
Is this something I need to worry about? If so, what should I do? I thought of adding a counter to the global list to see when an Item is not needed anymore and remove its reference.

**Edit:**
It is in fact a design problem, I think. I will discard the idea of a global list and instead loop through all Collections and see if they have the needed Item already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bit of a design problem, do you really need the global list?

Apart from weakreferences that Jon mentions, you could also periodically rebuild the global list (for example after deleting a collection) or only build it dynamically when you need it and release it again.

You'll have to decide which method is most appropriate, we don't have enough context here.

Answer (score 2):

If the global list *needs* references to the items then you can't realistically free them. Do you actually need references to the items in the global list? When should you *logically* be able to remove items from the global list?

You could consider using [weak references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404247.aspx) in the global list, and periodically pruning the [`WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) values themselves if their referents have been collected.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning weak references - I didn't know about them. But I don't think they are relevant for my problem.